# How to use Nutch API into java application?

Tags: java, web-crawler, nutch

I want to use Nutch API into my java application to crawl *pdf* links from a website for analyses, how can I do it using the Nutch jar in my java application? Can I have an example?

Comment: See how it's done in this sample GitHub repository: https://github.com/yegor256/nutch-in-java Here Nutch is used from the Java app, not from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

1st you need to run Nutch as a server by downloading and extract Nutch and then by giving the command,

```
bin/nutch startserver
```

After that you can use a REST client like **RestTemplate** in Java and call required APIs. Following is the documentation for all the REST APIs provided by Nutch.

https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch_1.X_RESTAPI/RunningJobsTutorial

Comment: Link is broken. This one seems to work: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/Nutch+1.X+RESTAPI .

Comment: As an aside, the Nutch web API is definitely NOT a RESTful API.